# View Controller perform twice using Segue in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, segue, xcode8, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having a problem in Swift 3.0 right now.

[image]

As attached picture (a), I embedded navigationController into **ViewController.swift**. ViewController.swift have button to connect to UITableCell **MovementStatusVC.swift**. And **MovementDetailsVC.swift** is to display all value from table cell.

The problem that i'm facing right now is when I create button in **MovementDetailsVC.swift** and perform segue to pass the data inside **"EditData"** function, Page display twice.

**MovementDetailsVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
class MovementDetailsVC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func EditData(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditMovementDetails", sender: self)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

The **EditMovementDetailsVC.swift** controller display twice when I tap Edit button in MovementDetailsVC.swift as shown as in picture below.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I'm using **perform segue** and **prepare segue** in **MovementDetailsVC.swift**

How to fix it so the view only perform one time ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the Edit button in your storyboard already have a segue leading to the MovementDetailsVC.swift page? If yes, you don't need to call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditMovementDetails", sender: self)`. You only need prepare segue to give the VC all the information it needs to display.

Comment: I see. let me try it first . I'll let you know later .

Comment: It does not work . . the value cannot be passed into EditMovementDetailsVC

Comment: If I don't write perform segue, the value cannot be passed into other page. I want the value passed into other page and view controller display only one time

Comment: Try dragging the  segue from the MovementDetailsVC itself to EditMovementDetailsVC in the story board instead of from the button. This way it will only fire when you call performSegue and not when tapping on the button.